# I'm trying to get my CircleAvatar widget to position as in the following image but I can't seem to make that happen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xP6A.png)Here is my code. I tried using the bottom constructor from the appbar and I tried using the CircleAvatar in the body but I can't seem to make it so that it would position at the middle of the appbar and the body. Any tips maybe? Since I'm new to the mobile development world.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignInPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignInPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFf65d46),
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(100), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100)
              // bottomLeft: Radius.circular(-1000),
              ),
        ),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(250),
          child: Container(),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: const [
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/logo_2.png'),
            radius: 75,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: UI Reference]

Comment: can you include the ui image of what you want?

Comment: Hi! Sorry I forgot to attach the UI Image. Thankyou for reminding me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of put that in body, try this:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(250),
    child: Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      children: [
        AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFf65d46),
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(100),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100)
                // bottomLeft: Radius.circular(-1000),
                ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: -75 ,
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/logo_2.png'),
            radius: 75,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  body: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: const [],
  ),
)
```

[image]